# Media query works when resize chrome but not toogle device responsive mode in chrome

Tags: html, css

This is an full-stack developer and I met one problem.
My website is responsive website and use media query(max-width).
I test is in chrome website and when I resize the chrome, it is working but not working when I test with toogle device toolbar.
Please check attached image.
[using toogle device toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMBQh.jpg)

[resize the chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwJSh.jpg)

As you can see in the first image, I set device size as Mobile L(425px)
but @media (max-width: 991px) query working
But in the second image you can see @media (max-width: 767px) query working.

Thank you for read my problem.

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome on SO: how are we supposed to help if you don't share a short, complete and verifiable example of the issue? Without it we can just guess.

Comment: have you set your viewport meta?

Comment: It is working.
Viewport meta helps me a lot.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
Thanks asiboe